# lcov doesn't match gcov coverage results for a googletest unit test

Tags: c++, code-coverage, googletest, gcov, lcov

I'm trying to gather coverage results on a library file foobar.cpp by creating a googletest unit tests for the souce file and then using gcov for coverage results, finally using lcov to produce an html document.

I've gotten unit testing and gcov results to work okay BUT lcov never depicts proper coverage results, omitting my foobar.cpp .gcov results completely?

I have a unit testing platform set up essentially like this:

#### Directories:

```
~/svn/googletest-read-only/
    /src
        gtest_main.cc
        gtest-all.cc
    /include
~/code/proj/
    foobar.cpp 
    foobar.hpp
~/code/proj/unittest/
    foobar_test.cpp
    Makefile
```

Everything run from **unittest/**, I make `unittest/ $ make`, producing an executable **foobar_test** in this folder. The **main()** is in **googletest/src/gtest_main.cc** file. My Makefile is based on googletest's and has these notable settings:

#### Makefile:

`CXXFLAGS += -g -O0 --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Wall -Wextra -pthread
LDFLAGS = -lpthread -lgcov
foobar_test : foobar.o foobar_test.o gtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@`

I run the executable once `$ ./foobar_test`. This produces .gcda's to match each source's .gcno (4x total: foobar, foobar_test, gtest_main, and gtest-all).

Then run `$ gcov foobar.cpp` on only foobar.cpp (I've tried alternatives like `$ gcov *.cpp` as well...using only foobar_test.cpp doesn't work). This produces stdout which includes a bunch of /usr/lib crap, but also MY result: **File '../foobar.cpp'; Lines executed:61.25% of 80; ..`** and creates my .gcov files.

Inspecting my .cpp.gcov file it shows good hit's as described above for 61.25% of lines. At this point I have 4x .gcda, 4x ,gcno, and about 20x other .gcov files.

Now, when I try to use lcov here `lcov --directory . -c -o result.info` it goes wrong.

#### lcov Results:

````
Capturing coverage data from .
Found gcov version: 4.4.7
Scanning . for .gcda files ...
Found 4 data files in .
Processing ./gtest_main.gcda
geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for foobar.cpp.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for *more c++ files*.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
Processing ./foobar.gcda
geninfo: WARNING: no data found for /home/asdf/code/proj/foobar.cpp
Processing ./foobar_test.gcda
geninfo: WARNING: no data found for /home/asdf/code/proj/unittest/foobar_test.cpp
Processing ./gtest-all.gcda
Finished .info-file creation```
````

Viewing the lcov output after a `$ genhtml report.info --output-directory report && firefox report/index.html` shows only about 5 directories that don't include ANY foobar* files?

I've tried multiple combinations of `$ gcov []cpp` as well as `$ lcov --base-directory [] --directory [] -c -o` to no avail. Also tried soft linking some source files around, no help.

What needs to change in my setup or commands?? Commenters are welcome to suggest a better solution altogether.

Comment: did you figure the "geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for foobar.cpp.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!" warning?